# add a publickey to server for SCP

Tags: scp, ssh-keys

My scenario is this, I am trying to SCP from server1 to server2 and and I need to create a public_key on server1 to allow server2 access to it. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ssh-copy-id

ssh to the server1

```
ssh server1
```

generate an ssh key on server1

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

copy this the public key to the autorized keys file on server2 of user "username"

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub username@server2
```

logout from server1

```
logout
```

Now you can login via ssh to server2 as username (or do scp stuff) from server1 without password.

For the other direction repeat the steps but switch the servers.