# How to deploye .war file in jboss server using shell script

Tags: shell, deployment, jenkins, jboss

I am on RedHat, using Jboss 5.x and Jenkins. My Jenkins is building the project perfect. I am coping the war file to deploy folder of Jboss with shell script.

When I am running the command on my terminal

```
scp source/example.war destination/deploy
```

scp command is able to copy the .war file into deploy folder and through url I am able to access it.

But the when I am writing the same command on jenkins it throws an error.

```
Permission denied
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

I guess it is because jenkins try to write the file and it does not have permission.

so how do i do that??

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SCP to copy your file from the Jenkins server to your Jboss server, you should declare the public SSH key of your jenkins user on the Jboss Server.

Please have a look to this answer: [add a publickey to server for SCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304317/add-a-publickey-to-server-for-scp)

Comment: I saw the post and i have generated ssh public key and private key. But i ma not sure where to copy that public key  and private key.

Comment: The ideal solution is to have the same user on the Jboss server and to add the public key in: ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

Comment: But jboss does not have ssh folder

Comment: Please create the .ssh folder in the home folder of the user running Joss, next create the authorized_keys file and copy the public ssh key.